# Is this equation solvable for R*?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I'm struggling to solve the following equation

$$
R^{*}*t = (||t||\ 0\ 0)^{T} 
$$
where **R*** is a 3x3 matrix and **t** a 3-vector. On the right side I have a column vector with **t**'s frobenius norm and 2 zeroes.

I re-wrote the equation like this but that didn't get me any closer to solving it for R*. So I was wndering if it is even possible? Or if I just made a basic mistake.

$$
R_{11}t_{1}+R_{12}t_{2}+R_{13}t_{3} = ||t||\\
R_{21}t_{1}+R_{22}t_{2}+R_{23}t_{3} = 0\\
R_{31}t_{1}+R_{32}t_{2}+R_{33}t_{3} = 0\\
$$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What if you take $R^*=[1/\|t\|,0,0]^Tt^T$? Here is a [related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170843/solving-ax-b-when-x-and-b-are-given/1171850#1171850).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can follow [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184976/3-variable-system-of-equations-when-all-set-to-zero/1185026#1185026) to see if the equations are solvable. In this case, your matrix $M$ will be:

$$ M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   R_{11} & R_{12} & R_{13}  & | & ||t|| \\
   R_{21} & R_{22} & R_{23} & | & 0 \\
   R_{31} & R_{32} & R_{33} & | & 0\\
  \end{array} } \right] $$

which is actually a shorthand for:

$$ M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   R_{11} & R_{12} & R_{13}\\
   R_{21} & R_{22} & R_{23}\\
   R_{31} & R_{32} & R_{33}\\
  \end{array} } \right] 
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   t_{1}\\
   t_{2}\\
   t_{3}\\
  \end{array} } \right] 
= \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   ||t||\\
   0\\
   0\\
  \end{array} } \right] 
$$

See if you can simplify the $3 \times 3$ matrix to become the identity matrix $I$.